# Error in parsing the android package on the device

Tags: android, parsing

I am trying to install my android app on my Galaxy ace phone which supports android 2.3.6 platform, API level 10 , but it is giving the error mentioned above.
I made the app in API level 15. I have set `android:minSdkVersion` to the API level 10. Still I am getting the same error. Any help will be appreciated. 
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10">`

Comment: That sounds like a corrupt APK file.

Comment: @CommonsWare but it works on the emulator

Comment: I am also getting such error on Android 2.3.6 platform, any help

Comment: Set the minSdkVersion to the API level 10. It worked for me. If your still getting the error, then maybe restart your phone.